# Generating and writing file bigger than system RAM in python

Tags: python

I know of this nice code that can generate files specific sizes and write them down .

```
def file_generator(location, size):
    filename = str(uuid.uuid4())
    with open('{0}{1}'.format(location, filename), 'wb') as target:
        target.write(os.urandom(size))
    return filename
```

How ever there is one small issue, it can't generate files bigger than system RAM it will fail with MemoryError, any idea how to write out the file in stream or somehow go around this issue ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`os.urandom` returns a string of the specified size. That string first needs to fit in memory. If that were a generator, things would work in a more memory efficient way.

It has nothing to do with system memory, however. It does not depend on the amount of physical RAM installed on your machine. It's limited by virtual memory, which is ~ 8TB for 64 bit programs on 64 bit Windows. However, that may involve swapping to disk, which becomes slow.

Therefore, potential solutions are:

1. switch from 32 bit Python to 64 bit Python and you'll not need to change the program at all. It will become significantly slower when you reach the end of physical RAM.
2. write the file in smaller parts, say 10 MB at a time.

In contrast to @quamrana's answer, I would not change the method signature. The caller could still choose 1 block à 8 GB, which has the same effect as before.

The following takes that burden from the caller:

```
def file_generator(location, size):
    filename = str(uuid.uuid4())
    chunksize = 10*1024*1024
    with open('{0}{1}'.format(location, filename), 'wb') as target:
        while size>chunksize:
            target.write(os.urandom(chunksize))
            size -= chunksize
        target.write(os.urandom(size))
    return filename
```

Answer (score 2):

When dealing with this kind of problem, the solution is breaking the data in chunks, choosing a favorable chunk size that:

- Is less than some limits there's no control on (in this case, *RAM* size)
- Is not too small, so the process doesn't take forever

In the example below, the wanted file size is split in (*32 MiB*) chunks (resulting a number (*>= 0*) of complete chunks, and possibly an incomplete chunk at the end).

*code.py*:

```python
import sys
import os
import uuid


DEFAULT_CHUNK_SIZE = 33554432  # 32 MiB


def file_generator(location, size):
    filename = str(uuid.uuid4())
    with open('{0}{1}'.format(location, filename), 'wb') as target:
        target.write(os.urandom(size))
    return filename


def file_generator_chunked(location, size, chunk_size=DEFAULT_CHUNK_SIZE):
    file_name = str(uuid.uuid4())
    chunks = size // chunk_size
    last_chunk_size = size % chunk_size
    with open("{0}{1}".format(location, file_name), "wb") as target:
        for _ in range(chunks):
            target.write(os.urandom(chunk_size))
        if last_chunk_size:
            target.write(os.urandom(last_chunk_size))
    return file_name


def main():
    file_name = file_generator_chunked("/tmp", 100000000)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Python {:s} on {:s}\n".format(sys.version, sys.platform))
    main()
```

Comment: You're welcome! This is a general problem. Also, if you don't care about the file contents, you could only call `os.urandom` once, and write that to file over and over again (for performance reasons), but given the fact that `os.urandom` is pretty fast I'm not sure about the performance gain (tests would reveal it).

Comment: I'm trying to avoid filesystem compression, at least that what I have red. since it would store the date differently if it would be full of 0 and if its random data.

Answer (score 0):

Write the file in blocks:

```
def large_file_generator(location, block_size, number_of_blocks):
    filename = str(uuid.uuid4())
    with open('{0}{1}'.format(location, filename), 'wb') as target:
        for _ in range(number_of_blocks):
            target.write(os.urandom(block_size))
    return filename
```